# "Argument list too long" in display all list elements

Tags: linux, shell, unix, makefile, command-line-arguments

I would like to dump the content in a list, but I have no idea how to solve this problem now.

When I try to display all elements in the list, shell shows:

> arguments list too long

in Makefile:

```
$(FILE_SOURCE:%= echo % >> $(FILE_LIST_TMP);)
```

Message:

```
execvp: /bin/sh: Argument list too long
```

Is there any other way to solve this problem without recompiling the kernel?

I would appreciate any suggestions. Thanks

Now I use perl to solve the problem. The following is my method:

```
while read line; do
  perl -e 'print "$$ARGV[0]\n"' $$line >> $(FILE_LIST_TMP) ; \
done < $(FILE_SOURCE)`
```

Comment: Your two examples here are completely different.  In the first one it appears that `FILE_SOURCE` is a make variable that contains a long list of files and in the second one it appears that `FILE_SOURCE` is a make variable that contains a filename of a file that contains a long list of files.  What is your situation?  If you show how `FILE_SOURCE` is defined we can be more help.

Comment: Just as a note, for the second example you can just run `cp $(FILE_SOURCE) $(FILE_LIST_TMP)` which will be a lot simpler and a LOT faster.

Answer (score 2):

One way you can make the command line much shorter is to not use `$(FILE_LIST_TMP)` in every single echo.  Instead, just use it once, like this:

```
(${FILE_SOURCE:%=echo %;}) > $(FILE_LIST_TMP)
```

Now instead of sending this to the shell:

```
echo foo >> my_temp_file ; echo bar >> my_temp_file ; echo baz >> my_temp_file; ..
```

you'll use this:

```
(echo foo; echo bar; echo baz;) > my_temp_file
```

which will be significantly shorter, especially as the number of files gets larger and especially if your temporary file name is long-ish.

Another trick you can play, if the files in `FILE_SOURCE` are all in a subdirectory that has a common path, is to `cd` there then you can omit that path from the `echo` lines.

However, even this may eventually not be sufficient if the list is long enough.

Comment: Starting with GNU make 4.0 and above, you can also use the `file` function to have make write the contents to a file first, before invoking the shell.  See http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/File-Function.html